# Numerical method for solving linear matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

What numerical methods for solving differential equations are particularly well suited for solving matrix differential equations of the form

$$  \frac{dF}{dt} = A(t)F(t)  ; \ \ \ F(0)= v $$

where function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable and function $A : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is continuous?

Comment: So, linear homogenous differential systems of equations.

Comment: Have you tried finding an *analytical* solution? How ugly is $A$?

Comment: Your notation is horrible. Uppercase for matrices is quite good. Uppercase for some vectors and lowercase for other vectors is not so good.

Comment: If $A(t)$ is indeed _only_ continuous (i.e. not differentiable or smooth or the like), then explicit and implicit Euler may be the best you can do, as higher order methods rely on the differentiability of the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment there is a lot of methods for solving such system. Depending on the information on $A(t)$ you have (is it a symmetric non-negative matrix ? a symplectic one ? etc.) and the accuracy you need the answer may vary.

For example the simplest method is to replace the time derivative by $(F(t_{n+1})-F(t_n))/\Delta t$.

This leads to two different discretization

- The **explicit** Euler method
  $$\frac{F(t_{n+1})-F(t_n)}{\Delta t}=A(t_n)F(t_n)$$
  i.e
  $$F(t_{n+1})=(Id +\Delta t A(t_n) ) F(t_n).$$
- The **implicit** Euler method
  $$\frac{F(t_{n+1})-F(t_n)}{\Delta t}=A(t_{n+1})F(t_{n+1})$$
  i.e $F(t_{n+1})$ is solution of the system
  $$(Id -\Delta t A(t_{n+1}) ) F(t_{n+1})= F(t_n).$$

The explicit method is straightforward but can be unstable when the implicit one is much more stable but require to solve a linear system at each step. So depending on the context you may choose one or the other.